# Whats the difference between service tomcat start/stop and ./catalina.sh run/stop

Tags: tomcat, apache-tomee

Whats the difference between service tomcat start/stop and ./catalina.sh run/stop in Tomcat or TomEE?

Do they do exactly the same thing?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

`catalina.sh run` starts tomcat in the foreground, displaying the logs on the console that you started it. Hitting Ctrl-C will terminate tomcat.

`startup.sh` will start tomcat in the background. You'll have to `tail -f logs/catalina.out` to see the logs.

Both will do the same things, apart from the foreground/background distinction.

Actually, `startup.sh` is quite small. If you inspect the file, you'll see that it in turn calls `catalina.sh start`. And in `catalina.sh` you can just search for occurrences of *run* and *start* in order to see the difference in how they're handled.

`service tomcat start` is typically starting a daemon in the background on Linux (or *nix), through yet another (non-tomcat) OS-script e.g. in `/etc/init.d`. It typically also takes care of running tomcat *as a specific user* (often called "tomcat" or similar). If you're using your Linux-distribution's tomcat, you should *only* start with this script. Otherwise you're risking that temporary files or log files can't be overwritten, because they belong to a different user that you used to start tomcat with earlier.