# How to call Tomcat startup.bat in java code

Tags: java, windows, tomcat, cmd

Tomcat startup.bat is called with Process in the Java code, which will create a new CMD window, and the rest of my Java code will not execute.Do I need to start a new Thread to do this? but even then I still can't get the br.

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process process;
BufferedReader br = null;
try {
    process = runtime.exec(command);
    runtime.gc();
    String line = null;
    String content = "";
    br = new BufferedReader(new 
    InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        content += line + "\r\n";
    }
    System.out.println(content);
} catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
} finally {
    if (br != null) {
        br.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try with `process.getErrorStream()`?

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat's `startup.bat` invokes `catalina.bat start`, which always opens a new window.

Try `catalina.bat run` instead, which will start Tomcat in the current window.

More details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29984238/whats-the-difference-between-service-tomcat-start-stop-and-catalina-sh-run-sto) and [here](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/tomcat-the-definitive/9780596101060/ch01s02.html).